# How to extract annonym javascript functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I defined my javascript jquery function in a separate file:

```
function setupSlider($, url) {
    genImgUrl = url + '/gensvg/';
    $("#slider").slider({
        min : -2000,
        max : 2000,
        value : 0,
        change : function(event, ui) {
            $('#svgImg').hide();
            $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                url : genImgUrl,
           ...
        },
        slide : function(event, ui) {
            var v = 50;
            ...
            $('#value').text(ui.value).css('left', (v - 0.5) + '%');
        }
    });
    $('#min').text($('#slider').slider('option', 'min'));
    $('#max').text($('#slider').slider('option', 'max'));
};
```

I would like to separate the functions for the `change` and `slide` option into a *defined* function `changeAction` and `slideAction`. But I have problems with my parameters `$`, `genImgUrl` and the *jquery slider* parameters `event`, `ui`. How do you merge them? You need the bind function, right?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure I get the question. Define a function that takes two params. Use that function reference as the value of `slide` (say). When it's called it'll get the two params.

Comment: is jQuery not loading to the global `$` variable, is that why you are passing it?

Comment: Needs 4 parameters `function slideAction(event, ui, $, genImgUrl)` or `function slideAction($, genImgUrl, event, ui)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
function getChangeAction(url) {
    var imgUrl = url;
    return function(event, ui) {
        $('#svgImg').hide();
        $.ajax({
           type : "POST",
           url : imgUrl,
        ...
    }
}

function slideAction(event, ui) {
    var v = 50;
    ...
    $('#value').text(ui.value).css('left', (v - 0.5) + '%');
}

function setupSlider($, url) {
    genImgUrl = url + '/gensvg/';
    $("#slider").slider({
        min : -2000,
        max : 2000,
        value : 0,
        change : getChangeAction(genImgUrl),
        slide : slideAction
        }
    });
    $('#min').text($('#slider').slider('option', 'min'));
    $('#max').text($('#slider').slider('option', 'max'));
};
```

This way you would pass the `genImgUrl` into the scope of the change-callback. `event` and `ui` will be passed when called, and `$` is declared global.

Comment: That's my favorite! The functions aside the main function, just for the general view.. Thanks! Removed the jquery parameter $ (global!)

Answer (score 2):

Just declare them nested so that you still have access to the scope of `$` and `genImgUrl`.

```
function setupSlider($, url) {
    var genImgUrl = url + '/gensvg/';
//  ^^^ this was supposed to be local I guess
    function onchange(event, ui) {
        $('#svgImg').hide();
        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : genImgUrl,
        …
    }
    function onslide(event, ui) {
        var v = 50;
        …
        $('#value').text(ui.value).css('left', (v - 0.5) + '%');
    }
    $("#slider").slider({
        min: -2000,
        max: 2000,
        value: 0,
        change: onchange,
        slide: onslide 
    });
    $('#min').text($('#slider').slider('option', 'min'));
    $('#max').text($('#slider').slider('option', 'max'));
}
```

This is - except for the names of the functions - exactly equivalent to what your code does.

Comment: i like it very much. actually i didn't understood your comment earlier. this way `$, url` are available in the child functions too with their `event, ui` args. nice one.

Comment: Nested looks nice but I would prefer to have it outside the function. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

so you want to use it like:

```
function changeAction(event, ui, url) { // write in global scope
    $('#svgImg').hide();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url, // this gets updated when setupSlider gets called.
        ...
    });
}

function slideAction(event, ui) { // write in global scope
    var v = 50;...
    $('#value').text(ui.value).css('left', (v - 0.5) + '%');
}

function setupSlider($, url) {
    var genImgUrl = url + '/gensvg/'; // declare with var keyword here.
    $("#slider").slider({......
        change: function(event, ui){ changeAction(event, ui, genImgUrl); }, //<--pass it here
        slide: slideAction // <----and here
    });
    $('#min').text($('#slider').slider('option', 'min'));
    $('#max').text($('#slider').slider('option', 'max'));
};
```

Answer (score 0):

That's what I end up with:

```
function setupSlider(url) {
    $("#slider").slider({
        min : -2000,
        max : 2000,
        value : 0,
        change : changeAction(url),
        slide : slideAction
    });
    $('#min').text($('#slider').slider('option', 'min'));
    $('#max').text($('#slider').slider('option', 'max'));
    $('#middle').text(0);
};

function changeAction(url) {
    var genImgUrl = url + '/gensvg/';
    return function(event, ui) {
        $('#svgImg').hide();
        $.blockUI();
        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : genImgUrl,
            data : {
                year : ui.value
            },
            success : function(imageName) {
                var i = $('<img />').attr('src', genImgUrl + imageName).load(
                        function() {
                            $('#svgImg').attr('src', i.attr('src'));
                            $('#svgImg').fadeIn();
                            $.unblockUI();
                        });
            },
            error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $.unblockUI();
                alert("error status " + textStatus);
            },
            dataType : "text"
        });
    };
}

function slideAction(event, ui) {
    var v = 50;
    if (ui.value > 0) {
        v = (ui.value / 40) + v;
    }
    if (ui.value < 0) {
        v = v - (Math.abs(ui.value) / 40);
    }
    $('#value').text(ui.value).css('left', (v - 0.5) + '%');
}
```

Thanks to [Florian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1658676/florian-gl)